# How do i fix a breakpoint in Xcode. Or should i say how can i find the root error for a breakpoint?

Tags: xcode

i keep getting this displayed on my standard editor view in XCODE. [  if (self.dieImage == nil)     Thread 1: breakpoint 1.1  ]

Answer (score 0):

That's not an error.  It means you set a spot for the debugger to stop so you can inspect it.  If you look on the left side of the screen where the line numbers are, you will see a little blue marker  [image].  Drag that marker to the right (onto your code) and it will disappear.

Answer (score 0):

(First check if the actions that you have linked up in your linker in your story board is existent in your header files you may have accidentally deleted the action and that may cause and error, make sure that everything is connected properly and everything that IS connected is declared if this does not work then do underneath)

This will help a bit more, where your files are look on the top bar. You will see many icons. Find the icon that is a arrow pointing to the right.

Once you click on this you will see a list of all your break points click on your one and hit delete. :) Fixed. If this does not fix your error, then it is a problem with your code or story board.

(Check if the actions that you have linked up in your linker in your story board is existent in your header files you may have accidentally deleted the action and that may cause and error, make sure that everything is connected properly and everything that IS connected is declared if this does not work then do underneath)

Hope this fixed your error.

Ajay Venkat